# ABCPDF Gecko on Azure WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, abcpdf, azure-webjobs

Have ABCPDF Gecko Engine turning webpage into PDF.  Works fine locally, but when pushing to azure webjobs I dont know how to debug this.  I am not ecen sure what that line of code (3518) is, as there are different versions out and its throwing an error from somewhere that doesn't have code.

### C# Code

```
    var url = "http://www.woot.com";
    Log("AddingImageUrl {0}", url);
    var theID = _doc.AddImageUrl(url);
    while (true)
    {
        if (!_doc.Chainable(theID))
        {
            break;
        }
        _doc.Page = _doc.AddPage();
        SetupRectangle();
        theID = _doc.AddImageToChain(theID);
    }
```

### Logs :

```
[04/30/2014 15:15:31 > 865961: INFO] AddingImageUrl http://www.woot.com
[04/30/2014 15:15:36 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:38 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:40 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:43 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:45 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] ??????????p: T###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (serif): file c:/WSG/Projects/ABCpdf/Source/mozilla-release/gfx/thebes/gfxFont.cpp, line 3518
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] 
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Internal.PDFException: Failed to add HTML: Remote process terminated unexpectedly. (Possible causes: Out of memory or corrupted/incorrect version of XULRunner folder.). ---> WebSupergoo.TaskGarden.RemoteProcessTerminatedException: Remote process terminated unexpectedly.
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] 
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] Server stack trace: 
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.TaskGarden.Core.RpcCaller.EndCall(IAsyncResult result, Object[]& outArgs)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.TaskGarden.Core.RpcCaller.Call(MethodBase method, Object[] args)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.TaskGarden.Instance`1.Invoke(IMessage msg)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] 
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ] Exception rethrown at [0]: 
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Internal.Gecko.IGeckoWorker.AddImageUrl(String url, Double pageWidthMm, Double pageHeightMm, AddImageUrlOptions options, UInt32& numCommands, Byte[]& data)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc.AddUrlHtml(String urlOrHtml, Boolean isHtml, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
[04/30/2014 15:15:47 > 865961: ERR ]    at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
```

Answer (score 1):

ABCpdf Gecko engine fails when deployed as Azure webjob, instead you can deploy as a Azure Cloud Service(Classic) Web Role.

WebRole is required only in the case if Image or HTML needs to be converted to PDF.
If only text needs to be converted to PDF we can just host the application as an App Service or WebJob (WebRole or Cloud Service may not be required).

ABCpdf Azure deployment guide available here:

http://www.websupergoo.com/support-azure-abcpdf.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this can work in Azure Website due to sandbox limitation.

Comment: I would be so inclined but it seems to be getting further than the websites restriction Demonstrated here : http://abcpdf2.azurewebsites.net/   Error : Failed to add HTML: RPC to Gecko engine process failed.
Failed to create named pipe \\.\Pipe\TaskGarden_ctrl_09971bf3-908d-4874-b2a2-fadc108ac2a2.   This seems to have already fired the external program and then met with issues.

Comment: UI apis are disabled by the sandbox so you cannot use internet explorer for example from your Azure Website which is probably what this is using to create the PDF.